# Compare subfolders number in directories

Tags: python, directory

I have a part of script which counts a number of sub-folders in directories.
I have 5 directories and each have to contain the same number of subfolders.
What I want to get is to check or compare directories if they are equal, like:

```
dir1 = 12 subdirs
dir2 = 12 subdirs
dir3 = 12 subdirs
dir4 = 12 subdirs
dir5 = 12 subdirs
```

To get error and do things when one sub-folder is missing in one of the directories.

My script:

```
import os            

    root = 'F:\gop\gop_img_test\\2018-03-06'

    def count_subdirectories(root):
    return len([d for d in os.listdir(root) if 
    os.path.isdir(os.path.join(root, d))])

    subdirectory_counts = set()
    num_directories = 0
    len_subdirs = []
    for d in os.listdir(root):
    dir_to_check = os.path.join(root, d)
    if os.path.isdir(dir_to_check):

    num_subdirs = count_subdirectories(dir_to_check)
    num_directories += 1
    subdirectory_counts.add(num_subdirs)
    #data_dict = []
    #data_dict.append(num_subdirs)
    #print(data_dict)
    if len(set(len_subdirs)) == 1:
        print("All sub directories contain equal number of folders")
    else:
        print("Sub-directories do NOT contain equal numbers of folders")
        Join = input("veille passer plus loin ?? :")
        if Join.lower() == 'yes':
              ### doing my stuff    

        else:
            print("answer yes or not ")
```

With returns:

```
12
12
12
12
11
```

The number of subdirectories are not the same. How to check it with Python and, when numbers are not the same, do something?

Comment: Try also printing `dir_to_check` next to `num_subdirs` to see which one has one subdir less.

Comment: its a 5th one , but sometimes its can be 2nd, 1st etc

Comment: You could save the dir names and subdir numbers in a dict like `data_dict[dir_to_check] = num_subdirs`, and then (after the `for` loop is done, and your dict is complete), try to iterate over it and check which key has the minimum value (if any), and operate on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst no doubt not the most efficient way you could store the length of `num_subdirs` in a list and then check for duplicates.
One way to check to see if all value within the list are the same is to convert them to a set.
A set cannot contain duplicates, so if all values are the same then the sets length =1. e.g.

Add the following before the for loop:

```
len_subdirs = []
```

Then append the value to the list at the end of the loop:

```
len_subdirs.append(num_subdirs)
```

Check if all lengths are identical

```
if len(set(len_subdirs))==1:
    print("All sub directories contain equal number of folders")
else:
    print("Sub-directories do NOT contain equal numbers of folders")
```

This of course must iterate over all your directories. You could store the length of the first directory an then compare this on each loop and as soon as one does not match then you can stop the loop if required.

Comment: Ok Matt but how to store and compare it , and when is not same I can stop it with an ex. input:"Value not same , do You want continue.." etc ...

Comment: `All sub directories contain equal number of folders
All sub directories contain equal number of folders
All sub directories contain equal number of folders
All sub directories contain equal number of folders
Sub-directories do NOT contain equal numbers of folders`

Comment: that's what script returns

Comment: So what you are seeing returned is the result at the end of each loop (4x "ALL..." followed by 1x "...NOT..". The final check needs to be outside of the loop so it only checks once all directory lengths have been stored (the lengths are being stored in the `len_subdirs` list).